# Detecting stale asset with sprockets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, asset-pipeline, sprockets

In sprockets how do I detect if an asset is stale?

I've tried the following and my results were unexpected:

```
e = Rails.application.assets # sprockets env
x = Rails.application.assets.index

e['path/to/my/asset'].body
#=> prints asset

e['path/to/my/asset'].fresh?(x)
#=> true


# modify the asset file (to change mtime and digest)


e['path/to/my/asset'].fresh?(x)
#=> true

#!? Why wasn't that false?
```

The caching mechanism confuses me. Further, when inspecting the asset it tells me that the `mtime` is the original value, not time I modified the file above. Can someone explain what's going on here and how I can detect a stale asset? My hope is to leverage the sprockets dependency/caching system in my gem.

**My Goal:**

I'm creating a gem that finds assets in the pipeline and generates some content from them. This gem integrates with ActionView which complicates things by doing its own caching. I need some way to bust ActionView's cache if the asset in sprockets is stale and will be reloaded on next fetch. Rather than mirror sprocket's caching system in my gem, I was hoping to just ask sprockets about the state of its assets - which seems totally possible, if only I could figure out what was going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't answer how to get around this, but I can (with some confidence) tell you why its behaving as it is. Sprockets doesn't only `mtime` to determine staleness, it uses a digest of the file itself. It will return the asset as fresh first if the `mtime` hasn't been recently updated, and secondly if the hash digest is unchanged (for the relevant method, look [here for `dependency_fresh?`](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/blob/master/lib/sprockets/asset.rb)). Since a `touch` won't change the hash of a file, Sprockets will consider it fresh.

I don't know quite what you're goal is here, so I can't give much advice here. The dependency tracking that is used is mostly private, but it would be possible to hack around this to force a reset. If what you're looking for is a quick way to force an asset to be stale for the sake of local testing while developing a gem, you may consider creating a monkey patch for `Asset` or `ProcessedAsset` that can flush the old `mtime` and `digest` values.

---

EDIT - I've done a bit more digging, and I think I found some useful things. The `index` method on `assets` creates a new object on each call, and is in effect a snapshot of the assets at the time, while the environment will constantly refresh when you ask it for an asset - looking up an asset causes it to automatically refresh that asset if it is stale.

In theory, this should have a surprisingly easy solution - just invert your fresh calls to `x['path/to/asset'].fresh?(e)`.

Comment: Bubbles, thanks for the answer. I edited the question to reflect that I actually modified the file (not just touched it) as I knew about the digest hash. I'll update the question to discuss more about my goal.

Comment: Hmm. I think I actually dug a little too deep with my original answer. When you look up an asset like you're doing, you're actually creating a fresh asset - the `[]` lookup on `Sprockets::Environment` creates a fresh asset, and naturally a newly created asset will never not be fresh. If you can keep the reference alive that would work, but may not be convenient in every circumstance. I'm going to dig a bit more and get back to you.